# Split a pandas column of dictionaries into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following csv with first row as header:

```
id,data
a,"{'1': 0.7778, '3': 0.5882, '2': 0.9524, '4': 0.5556}"  
b,"{'1': 0.7778, '3': 0.5, '2': 0.7059, '4': 0.2222}"  
c,"{'1': 0.8182, '3': 0.2609, '2': 0.5882}"
```

I need to get to something like this

```
id      1      2      3      4  
 a 0.7778 0.9524 0.5882 0.5556
 b 0.7778 0.7059 0.5    0.2222
 c 0.8182 0.5882 0.2609    NaN
```

where the keys of the dictionary are the columns.

How can I do this using pandas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with Python's [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) module:

```
import ast
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/your.csv')
dict_df = pd.DataFrame([ast.literal_eval(i) for i in df.data.values])

>>> dict_df
        1       2       3       4
0  0.7778  0.9524  0.5882  0.5556
1  0.7778  0.7059  0.5000  0.2222
2  0.8182  0.5882  0.2609     NaN

df = df.drop('data',axis=1)
final_df = pd.concat([df,dict_df],axis=1)

>>> final_df
  id       1       2       3       4
0  a  0.7778  0.9524  0.5882  0.5556
1  b  0.7778  0.7059  0.5000  0.2222
2  c  0.8182  0.5882  0.2609     NaN
```